# The way Facebook structures its profile system

Tags: php, html, facebook, directory, profile

Can some one please explain to me how Facebook structures its profile system?

For example: when you go to **facebook.com/some.profile**, it shows you your profile, and that tells me that there is a file  in the Facebook's root directory called **some.profile**.

But how does it work that you can go to **facebook.com/some.profile/photos**? By this, **"some.profile"** becomes a directory(folder) itself, and the directory contains the "**photos"** file.

So how can **"some.profile"** be a file and a directory at the same time? Doesn't make sense. Can you please explain it to me?
Please include some code supporting your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Web applications use URL routing so that URL's are directed at endpoints inside the application, rather than simply at files on a file system.  For example, let's consider the URL to this question on Stack Overflow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493733
```

The code that powers Stack Overflow knows that you're requesting a question, (/questions) and it knows which question you want because you've specified the ID in the URL (/22493733).  Thus, after that data has been split into segments, it can try to fetch the data for that question from a data source and render the appropriate page.  There is no folder called questsions on the file system, nor is there a file in that folder for each question ID.

Comment: Thank you very much...and can you show me with a little bit of code?

Comment: Not really.  I of course don't have access to Facebook's source code and how you set up URL routing in your application will fully depend on what language, web framework and web server you're using.